# Error in `main': free(): invalid pointer (though no free or delete used)

Tags: c++

I have this simple code that i m trying to run in tutorialspoint.com

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vehicle {
    string vehicleNo;
    string color;

    protected:
    string getVehicleNo()
    {
        return vehicleNo;
    }

    string setVehicleNo(string num)
    {
        vehicleNo = num;
    }

    string getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    string setColor(string someColor)
    {
        color = someColor;
    }
};

class Car: public Vehicle {
    private:
    int distance;

    public:
    void setDistance(int a)
    {
        distance = a;
    }

    int calculateFare(int)
    {
        return distance * 5;
    }

    void displayInformation()
    {
        cout << distance << endl; 
    }

    void useSetVehicleNo(string num)
    {
        setVehicleNo(num);
    }

    string useSetColor(string someColor)
    {
        setColor(someColor);
    }

    string useGetVehicleNo()
    {
        return getVehicleNo();
    }

    string useGetColor()
    {
        return getColor();
    }
};

int main()
{
   //string exit=n;
   string vehicleNo;
   string color;
   Car car;

   cout << "Enter car number : " << endl;
   cin >> vehicleNo;
   car.useSetVehicleNo(vehicleNo);

   cout << "Enter car color : " << endl;
   cin >> color;
   car.useSetColor(color);

   //vehicleNo = car.useGetColor();
   //color = car.useGetVehicleNo();

   //cout << vehicleNo;
   //cout << color;


   return 0;
}
```

Running this is giving me the following output

> Enter car number :
>   1
>   Enter car color :
>   g
>
> *** Error in `main': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ff3aa205ba8 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: =========                                                                                                         /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7850e)[0x7ff3a969450e]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x5b5)[0x7ff3a96a0165]
>   main[0x400e97]
>   main[0x400c79]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ff3a963bfe0]
>   main[0x400ac9]
>
> ======= Memory map: ========                                                                                                         00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 fd:11f 59330668
>   /home/cg/roo                                                t/main
>   00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 fd:11f 59330668
>   /home/cg/roo                                                t/main
>   00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 fd:11f 59330668
>   /home/cg/roo                                                t/main
>   0140c000-0142d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [heap]
>   7ff3a961c000-7ff3a97d0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:11f 37749826
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibc-2.20.so
>   7ff3a97d0000-7ff3a99cf000 ---p 001b4000 fd:11f 37749826
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibc-2.20.so
>   7ff3a99cf000-7ff3a99d3000 r--p 001b3000 fd:11f 37749826
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibc-2.20.so
>   7ff3a99d3000-7ff3a99d5000 rw-p 001b7000 fd:11f 37749826
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibc-2.20.so
>   7ff3a99d5000-7ff3a99d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   7ff3a99d9000-7ff3a99ef000 r-xp 00000000 fd:11f 37749844
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibgcc_s-4.9.2-20141101.so.1             7ff3a99ef000-7ff3a9bee000 ---p
>   00016000 fd:11f 37749844                  /usr/lib64/l
>   ibgcc_s-4.9.2-20141101.so.1
>   7ff3a9bee000-7ff3a9bef000 r--p 00015000 fd:11f 37749844
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibgcc_s-4.9.2-20141101.so.1
>   7ff3a9bef000-7ff3a9bf0000 rw-p 00016000 fd:11f 37749844
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibgcc_s-4.9.2-20141101.so.1
>   7ff3a9bf0000-7ff3a9cf7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:11f 37749280
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibm-2.20.so
>   7ff3a9cf7000-7ff3a9ef6000 ---p 00107000 fd:11f 37749280
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibm-2.20.so
>   7ff3a9ef6000-7ff3a9ef7000 r--p 00106000 fd:11f 37749280
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibm-2.20.so
>   7ff3a9ef7000-7ff3a9ef8000 rw-p 00107000 fd:11f 37749280
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibm-2.20.so
>   7ff3a9ef8000-7ff3a9fe8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:11f 37749829
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibstdc++.so.6.0.20
>   7ff3a9fe8000-7ff3aa1e8000 ---p 000f0000 fd:11f 37749829
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibstdc++.so.6.0.20
>   7ff3aa1e8000-7ff3aa1f0000 r--p 000f0000 fd:11f 37749829
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibstdc++.so.6.0.20
>   7ff3aa1f0000-7ff3aa1f2000 rw-p 000f8000 fd:11f 37749829
>   /usr/lib64/l
>   ibstdc++.so.6.0.20
>   7ff3aa1f2000-7ff3aa207000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   7ff3aa207000-7ff3aa228000 r-xp 00000000 fd:11f 37856921
>   /usr/lib64/l                                                d-2.20.so 
>   7ff3aa412000-7ff3aa417000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   7ff3aa424000-7ff3aa428000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   7ff3aa428000-7ff3aa429000 r--p 00021000 fd:11f 37856921
>   /usr/lib64/l                                                d-2.20.so 
>   7ff3aa429000-7ff3aa42a000 rw-p 00022000 fd:11f 37856921
>   /usr/lib64/l        7ff3aa429000-7ff3aa42a000 rw-p 00022000 fd:11f
>   37856921                  /usr/lib64/l
>   d-2.20.so
>   7ff3aa42a000-7ff3aa42b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   7fff1dddb000-7fff1ddfc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [stack]
>   7fff1ddfe000-7fff1de00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vdso]
>   ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vsyscall]                                                  Aborted
>   (core dumped)

Comment: Turn up your warning level.

Comment: add `#include <string>` and if the function is not returning anything then change return type to `void`

Comment: Compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have three functions that have a return type different than `void` where you don't have a valid `return` statement.

If you turn your warning level up, your compiler will tell you about them. When using `g++ -Wall`, I get the following messages:

```
socc.cc: In member function ‘std::string Vehicle::setVehicleNo(std::string)’:
socc.cc:19:4: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
socc.cc: In member function ‘std::string Vehicle::setColor(std::string)’:
socc.cc:29:4: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
socc.cc: In member function ‘std::string Car::useSetColor(std::string)’:
socc.cc:60:7: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
       }

   ^
```

Calling such functions leads to undefined behavior.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **6.6.3 `return` statement**
>
> 2 ...
>   ...
>   Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
>   behavior in a value-returning function.

You can fix the problem by adding a suitable `return` statement. E.g.

The first function:

```
string setVehicleNo(string num)
{
   vehicleNo = num;
   return vehicleNo; // Add this, maybe?
}
```

The second function:

```
string setColor(string someColor)
{
   color = someColor;
   return color;  // Add this, maybe
}
```

The third function:

```
string useSetColor(string someColor)
{
   return setColor(someColor); // Add the return, maybe?
}
```

Comment: thanks... i cant believe i made this stupid mistake but its due to the fact that i was depending on the compiler to return an error for this mistake.

Bravo :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problems are here:

```
   string setVehicleNo(string num)
// ^^^^^^
   {
        vehicleNo = num;
   }
```

You are defining a return type but don't return a value actually (you should have gotten a compiler warning about this).

To fix either specify a `void` return type, or return a value.

Analogous for your other functions. See a fixed [demo here](http://ideone.com/XYJ3SX).

Answer (score 2):

Do the following changes in your code :

**first -**

```
string setVehicleNo(string num)
// ^^^^^^
   {
        vehicleNo = num;
   }
```

**second -**

```
string setColor(string someColor)
// ^^^^^^
    {
        color = someColor;
    }
```

**third -**

```
string useSetColor(string someColor)
//^^^^^^
    {
        setColor(someColor);
    }
```

You have assign return type to `string` but not returning any value. changed it to `void`. see the changes made here http://ideone.com/n1Wg15

Comment: Yes one can fix this way or the other way, as mentioned in my answer.